# Errors when creating ffmpeg thumbnails

Tags: ffmpeg

When creating thumbnails with version V2. the Number of images was only 4, each image has 25 frames.

Updated to v4, the number of images increased to 7 but still skips. That is, some frames are missing, there should be only 8.

The video lasts 1:37:00, the number of frames should be 194. This is 8 images. Again, each image has 25 frames.

On the forums, unfortunately, I did not find a solution, please help

A command that generates images with 25 frames each. Immediately apply cropped

```
crop=$(ffmpeg -i $file -ss 10 -t $(($time_v/2)) -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print  $NF }' | tail -1)

sudo ffmpeg -i $file -vsync vfr -vf "select=isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t\,"$inter"),"$crop",scale=-2:"$Himg",tile="$Ycoun"x"$Xcoun -qscale:v 2 $pathnew"/thumbnails%01d.jpg"
```

As a result of executing the command, some frames are lost. What could be the problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YDhT.jpg)

Comment: Instead of showing the code, please show the exact command that is run (i.e. not `$file` but the actual filename) and the full, uncut command line output from ffmpeg. Seems like the input file is damaged – does it work with another file or if you use ` -f lavfi -i testsrc` instead of  `-i $file`?

Comment: sudo ffmpeg -i /var/www/uploads/2333.avi -vsync vfr -vf "select=isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t\,30),scale=-1:80,tile=5x5" -qscale:v 2 "/var/www/uploads/thumbnails%01d.jpg"

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/ZmmYX0Y/9207334540.jpg

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to fully screen the process

Comment: The completion of the process: https://i.ibb.co/ykGK2bJ/gifvd.gif

Comment: Next time please [edit] the question and add the information. You could also output the log to a text file and copy it from there. As I said, the input file seems damaged. Does it work with another file?